# Python does not recognize soft link change

Tags: python, linux

```
import os
import sys
from time import sleep

soft = 'link.lnk'
fd_soft = open(soft, 'a');
i = 0;
while 1:
    try:
        line = 'the count is %d' %(i)
        print line
        fd_soft.write(line);
        i += 1;
        sleep(1);
        fd_soft.flush()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "interrupt ctrl c"
        fd_soft.close()
        sys.exit(0)
```

link.lnk is a soft link to a old.txt file.
This script opens the soft link and writes a number to it every second.
During runtime i change link.lnk to point to a new file with

```
ln -sf new.txt link.lnk
```

because i want to write to new.txt, but the process still keeps writing to old file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still using the old file handle that you opened before you changed the symlink.  If you want new writes to be reflected in the new symlink, you'll need to re-open the file handle before each write and close it after each write.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it works, but wont there be performance hits, Im writing a program that could maybe log a 100 lines per minute

Comment: Then in that case you should setup a signal handler in your code to listen for the SIGHUP signal and close the file handle, possibly wait a second, then open a new file handle, and continue on with its logging so that you can hold onto the old filehandle and only give it up when you receive the SIGHUP signal insetad of opening and closing for every write.  Whatever's changing your symlinks should send a SIGHUP to your python process before it changes the symlink.  This is the basic idea behind logrotate.   More info on signal handling in python here: https://pymotw.com/2/signal/

Comment: Good idea, but i cannot make any changes to the log writing applications, ill probably use something like logrotate